# putStrLn IO() error when trying to display a list

Tags: haskell, io

I was playing around with making custom list displays. The concept is really simple but I keep getting an IO() error. My code is:

```
displayList :: [Int] -> IO()
displayList [] = putStrLn ""
displayList (firstUnit:theRest) =  putStrLn (show firstUnit ++ "\n" ++ 
                                   displayList theRest)
```

The error code I am getting is:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘[Char]’ with actual type ‘IO ()’
• In the second argument of ‘(++)’, namely ‘(displayList theRest)’
  In the first argument of ‘putStrLn’, namely
    ‘((show firstUnit) ++ (displayList theRest))’
  In the expression:
    putStrLn ((show firstUnit) ++ (displayList theRest))
```

The specific part of the line that is getting the error is the `displayList theRest` not the `putStrLn ((show firstUnit) ++` part.

I think I understand what is happening which is that when `displayList theRest` is called in the line with the error it has the potential eventually after a few recursive calls to return an IO() type from the line `displayList [] = putStrLn ""` which is not supported as input in the `putStrLn` function. Would anyone know a way to solve this?

Comment: `displayList` never returns a String in any case. It always returns `IO`, so `... ++ displayList theRest` doesn't make sense. You'd be better off having this function construct and return a String, then printing the String as needed.

Comment: the problem is that you're trying to concatenate a `String` (or `[Char]`, which means the same thing) with the result of `displayList`, which is `IO ()` - and it's fairly obvious you can't do this. I'm not sure exactly how you want this to be output, but you probably want to call `putStrLn (show firstUnit)` then recursively call `displayList` on `theRest`. And by "then" I mean sequence the 2 IO actions, either in a `do` block or with the `>>` operator (which is the same, it's what the `do` block translates to).

Comment: You'd have the same problem in any programming language (including imperative languages). You need to figure out whether you want `displayList` to build and return a string, or whether it should output stuff (and return nothing).

Comment: What you currently have is like saying `printf("%d\n%s", firstUnit, printf(theRest))`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The Problem

The problem with your code is fairly obvious: as the compiler tells you, you're trying to concatenate a string (`((show firstUnit) ++`) with an `IO()` (the return type of your function)

## Solution

The solution can take two paths: either you want a function that returns the whole string, and then prints it all in one, or just print it step by step recursively. What I mean is:

### Return a string

```
displayList :: [Int] -> IO()
displayList = putStrLn . helper
  where
    helper :: [Int] -> String
    helper [] = ""
    helper (n:ns) = show n ++ "\n" ++ helper ns
```

This approach works fine, but I believe it's not tidy nor clear.

### Better version

```
displayList' :: [Int] -> IO()
displayList' [] = putStrLn ""
displayList' (n:ns) =  putStrLn (show n) >> displayList' ns
```

I think you can see how this version is easier to read. Also note that `print :: Show a => a -> IO()` works exactly as `putStrLn . show`

Comment: Even better version: `displayList ns = mapM_ print ns`